# NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() is always true on mac os sierra

Tags: macos, silverlight, operating-system

I have an OOB silverlight application.
In my code I use `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` and `NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged` to monitor the client network status.
Until now `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` returned a "realistic" result both on Windows (7, 8, 10...) and os X.

On a recent test we found an issue on sierra: on this os the return value of `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` is always true.

Is there another way to reliably detect the "online" status of the client?
(no, polling on a known url is not an option..)